# java returns false for File#exists when it does

Tags: java, windows, file, path

`new File("C:/Users/jredfox/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/wt.exe").exists()` returns false when the exact path copied and pasted to command prompt starts windows terminal. Any ideas of how to get it working?

also tried

```
        File f = new File("C:/Users/jredfox/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps");
        for(File a : f.listFiles())
        {
            System.out.println(a + " isSymbolicLink:" + Files.isSymbolicLink(a.toPath()) + " exists:" + Files.exists(a.toPath()));
        }
```

Comment: That is clearly not what is in the code as it's missing the quotes... do not retype code into your question, always copy/paste from the compilable source.

Comment: The first thing you should do is remove all usage of java.io.File, and replace it with the [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html) and [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html) classes of the java.nio.file package, which is much more accurate and informative.  What does `Files.exists(Path.of("C:/Users/jredfox/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/wt.exe"))` return?

Comment: Believe the JVM.  Your code is wrong.  Doesn't matter what you believe.

Comment: Possibly your java process has no read access to `C:/Users/jredfox/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps` or any parent directory in that tree.

Comment: @VGR same result on both java 8 and 18 with the paths api

Comment: @duffymo where.exe shows the path to wt properly. I copied it used it to launch wt. but then when I check if it exists it doesn't work

Comment: @Gardener then how to check if those alias's exist. Files#isSymbolicLink returns false

Comment: Windows “Reparse Point” magic at work… Note that NIO `Files.isExecutable(p)`, the question you’re actually interested in, does work. Further, `Files.exists(p, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)` returns the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

couldn't seem to find an answer but I found a workaround.

```java
    private static boolean isWindows = osName.contains("windows");
    private static boolean isLinux = osName.contains("linux") || osName.contains("nux") || osName.contains("aix");
    private static boolean isMac = osName.contains("mac") && !isLinux || osName.contains("osx") || osName.contains("darwin");
    /**
     * find executeable from path. support for WUP and macOs apps as well as standard with and without extensions paths
     */
    public static String findExe(String name)
    {
        String ext = isWindows() ? ".exe" : isMac() ? ".app" : "";//TODO: test macOs and confirm functionality on windows
        String fname = name.contains(".") ? name : name + ext;
        boolean hasF = !ext.isEmpty();
        
        //search the full path of the dir before searching env path
        if(name.contains("/"))
        {
            File path = new File(name);
            File fpath = new File(fname);
            if(path.canExecute())
                return path.getPath();
            else if(hasF && isExe(fpath))
                return fpath.getPath();
        }

        for (String dirname : System.getenv("PATH").split(File.pathSeparator)) 
        {
            File file = new File(dirname, name);
            File ffile = new File(dirname, fname);
            
            //Windows 10 WUP support
            if(OSUtil.isWindows())
            {
                if(dirname.contains("WindowsApps"))
                {
                    File[] files = file.getParentFile().listFiles();
                    if(FileUtil.containsFile(files, file) && !file.isDirectory())
                        return file.getPath();
                    else if(FileUtil.containsFile(files, ffile) && !file.isDirectory())
                        return ffile.getPath();
                }
            }
            if (isExe(file))
                return file.getPath();
            else if(hasF && isExe(ffile))
                return ffile.getPath();
        }
        
        //macOS start here
        if(OSUtil.isMac())
        {
            for(String root : macAppPaths)
            {
                File app = new File(root, fname);
                if(isExe(app))
                    return app.getPath();
            }
        }
        
        return null;
    }
        public static boolean isWindows()
    {
        return isWindows;
    }
    
    public static boolean isMac()
    {
        return isMac;
    }
    
    public static boolean isLinux()
    {
        return isLinux;
    }
    public static boolean isExe(File f)
    {
        return (f.isFile() || f.getName().endsWith(".app")) && f.canExecute();
    }
```